# How to change the priority value for a profile in Pulseaudio sound cards

Tags: audio, pulseaudio, alsa, hdmi

This is the result I get when running `pactl list cards` on my Debian system.

```
Card #0
    Name: alsa_card.pci-0000_00_0e.0
    Driver: module-alsa-card.c
    Owner Module: 1
    Properties:
        alsa.card = "0"
        alsa.card_name = "HDA Intel PCH"
        alsa.long_card_name = "HDA Intel PCH at 0x82510000 irq 130"
        alsa.driver_name = "snd_hda_intel"
        device.bus_path = "pci-0000:00:0e.0"
        sysfs.path = "/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:0e.0/sound/card0"
        device.bus = "pci"
        device.vendor.id = "8086"
        device.form_factor = "internal"
        device.string = "0"
        device.description = "Built-in Audio"
        module-udev-detect.discovered = "1"
        device.icon_name = "audio-card-pci"
    Profiles:
        input:analog-stereo: Analog Stereo Input (sinks: 0, sources: 1, priority: 60, available: yes)
        output:analog-stereo: Analog Stereo Output (sinks: 1, sources: 0, priority: 6000, available: yes)
        output:analog-stereo+input:analog-stereo: Analog Stereo Duplex (sinks: 1, sources: 1, priority: 6060, available: yes)
        output:hdmi-stereo: Digital Stereo (HDMI) Output (sinks: 1, sources: 0, priority: 5400, available: yes)
        output:hdmi-stereo+input:analog-stereo: Digital Stereo (HDMI) Output + Analog Stereo Input (sinks: 1, sources: 1, priority: 5460, available: yes)
        output:hdmi-stereo-extra1: Digital Stereo (HDMI 2) Output (sinks: 1, sources: 0, priority: 5200, available: no)
        output:hdmi-stereo-extra1+input:analog-stereo: Digital Stereo (HDMI 2) Output + Analog Stereo Input (sinks: 1, sources: 1, priority: 5260, available: yes)
        output:hdmi-surround-extra1: Digital Surround 5.1 (HDMI 2) Output (sinks: 1, sources: 0, priority: 100, available: no)
        output:hdmi-surround-extra1+input:analog-stereo: Digital Surround 5.1 (HDMI 2) Output + Analog Stereo Input (sinks: 1, sources: 1, priority: 160, available: yes)
        output:hdmi-surround71-extra1: Digital Surround 7.1 (HDMI 2) Output (sinks: 1, sources: 0, priority: 100, available: no)
        output:hdmi-surround71-extra1+input:analog-stereo: Digital Surround 7.1 (HDMI 2) Output + Analog Stereo Input (sinks: 1, sources: 1, priority: 160, available: yes)
        output:hdmi-stereo-extra2: Digital Stereo (HDMI 3) Output (sinks: 1, sources: 0, priority: 5200, available: no)
        output:hdmi-stereo-extra2+input:analog-stereo: Digital Stereo (HDMI 3) Output + Analog Stereo Input (sinks: 1, sources: 1, priority: 5260, available: yes)
        output:hdmi-surround-extra2: Digital Surround 5.1 (HDMI 3) Output (sinks: 1, sources: 0, priority: 100, available: no)
        output:hdmi-surround-extra2+input:analog-stereo: Digital Surround 5.1 (HDMI 3) Output + Analog Stereo Input (sinks: 1, sources: 1, priority: 160, available: yes)
        output:hdmi-surround71-extra2: Digital Surround 7.1 (HDMI 3) Output (sinks: 1, sources: 0, priority: 100, available: no)
        output:hdmi-surround71-extra2+input:analog-stereo: Digital Surround 7.1 (HDMI 3) Output + Analog Stereo Input (sinks: 1, sources: 1, priority: 160, available: yes)
        off: Off (sinks: 0, sources: 0, priority: 0, available: yes)
    Active Profile: output:hdmi-stereo
    Ports:
        analog-input-internal-mic: Internal Microphone (priority: 8900, latency offset: 0 usec)
            Properties:
                device.icon_name = "audio-input-microphone"
            Part of profile(s): input:analog-stereo, output:analog-stereo+input:analog-stereo, output:hdmi-stereo+input:analog-stereo, output:hdmi-stereo-extra1+input:analog-stereo, output:hdmi-surround-extra1+input:analog-stereo, output:hdmi-surround71-extra1+input:analog-stereo, output:hdmi-stereo-extra2+input:analog-stereo, output:hdmi-surround-extra2+input:analog-stereo, output:hdmi-surround71-extra2+input:analog-stereo
        analog-input-headphone-mic: Microphone (priority: 8700, latency offset: 0 usec)
            Properties:
                device.icon_name = "audio-input-microphone"
            Part of profile(s): input:analog-stereo, output:analog-stereo+input:analog-stereo, output:hdmi-stereo+input:analog-stereo, output:hdmi-stereo-extra1+input:analog-stereo, output:hdmi-surround-extra1+input:analog-stereo, output:hdmi-surround71-extra1+input:analog-stereo, output:hdmi-stereo-extra2+input:analog-stereo, output:hdmi-surround-extra2+input:analog-stereo, output:hdmi-surround71-extra2+input:analog-stereo
        analog-output: Analog Output (priority: 9900, latency offset: 0 usec)
            Part of profile(s): output:analog-stereo, output:analog-stereo+input:analog-stereo
        hdmi-output-0: HDMI / DisplayPort (priority: 5900, latency offset: 0 usec, available)
            Properties:
                device.icon_name = "video-display"
                device.product.name = "MSI MP243"
            Part of profile(s): output:hdmi-stereo, output:hdmi-stereo+input:analog-stereo
        hdmi-output-1: HDMI / DisplayPort 2 (priority: 5800, latency offset: 0 usec, not available)
            Properties:
                device.icon_name = "video-display"
            Part of profile(s): output:hdmi-stereo-extra1, output:hdmi-stereo-extra1+input:analog-stereo, output:hdmi-surround-extra1, output:hdmi-surround-extra1+input:analog-stereo, output:hdmi-surround71-extra1, output:hdmi-surround71-extra1+input:analog-stereo
        hdmi-output-2: HDMI / DisplayPort 3 (priority: 5700, latency offset: 0 usec, not available)
            Properties:
                device.icon_name = "video-display"
            Part of profile(s): output:hdmi-stereo-extra2, output:hdmi-stereo-extra2+input:analog-stereo, output:hdmi-surround-extra2, output:hdmi-surround-extra2+input:analog-stereo, output:hdmi-surround71-extra2, output:hdmi-surround71-extra2+input:analog-stereo
```

Under Profiles I have `output:analog-stereo` with priority `6000` and `output:hdmi-stereo` with priority `5400`.

I tried to check how the audio worked by running the following

For `output:hdmi-stereo`

```
aplay -D plughw:0,3 /usr/share/sounds/alsa/Front_Right.wav
```

- No audio present

For `output:analog-stereo`

```
aplay -D plughw:0,0 /usr/share/sounds/alsa/Front_Right.wav
```

- Audio is present

This is my `pactl list short sinks`

```
0 alsa_output.pci-0000_00_0e.0.analog-stereo    module-alsa-card.c  s16le 2ch 44100Hz   SUSPENDED
```

So I see that the default is analog-stereo. So I changed that with the following

```
pactl set-card-profile 0 output:hdmi-stereo
pactl set-default-sink alsa_output.pci-0000_00_0e.0.hdmi-stereo
```

Now `pactl list short sinks` is

```
1   alsa_output.pci-0000_00_0e.0.hdmi-stereo    module-alsa-card.c  s16le 2ch 44100Hz   SUSPENDED
```

And when I run the following I have audio for both

`aplay -D plughw:0,3 /usr/share/sounds/alsa/Front_Right.wav` for `output:hdmi-stereo` - Audio is present

`aplay -D plughw:0,0 /usr/share/sounds/alsa/Front_Right.wav` for `output:analog-stereo` - Audio is present

I was wondering if the reason `output:analog-stereo` was playing in this setting was because it has a higher priority. Ideally I want both to run at same priority. Meaning I should not have to follow the steps I did to get `output:hdmi-stereo` playing. I need both to play anyway. Do I need to change its priority to match `output:analog-stereo` ? Make both 6000? How do I get that done?